# YUM broken after update libcurl on CentOS 6

Tags: centos6, yum

im update `libcurl` and now when update my server show this message:

```
[root@server ~]# yum
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   libnghttp2.so.14: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.6.6 (r266:84292, Aug 18 2016, 15:13:37)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)]

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to
the yum faq at:
  http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq
```

how can fix this?, i tried upgrading YUM via RPM But it does not work, on a post found what i need update Python to 2.7, how can resolve this?, thanks

this is my yum.log:

```
[root@server ~]# tail -n 10 /var/log/yum.log
Nov 15 04:12:37 Updated: ea-php55-php-gd-5.5.38-39.39.13.cpanel.x86_64
Nov 15 04:12:38 Updated: ea-php55-php-calendar-5.5.38-39.39.13.cpanel.x86_64
Nov 15 04:12:43 Updated: cpanel-wordpress-instance-manager-plugin-2.0.1-1.1.1.cpanel.noarch
Nov 20 13:04:28 Installed: epel-release-6-8.noarch
Nov 20 13:20:36 Updated: libssh2-1.8.0-8.0.cf.rhel6.x86_64
Nov 20 13:20:36 Installed: c-ares-1.15.0-1.0.cf.rhel6.x86_64
Nov 20 13:20:36 Updated: libcurl-7.62.0-1.0.cf.rhel6.x86_64
Nov 20 13:20:37 Installed: libmetalink-0.1.3-7.rhel6.x86_64
Nov 20 13:20:37 Updated: curl-7.62.0-1.0.cf.rhel6.x86_64
Nov 20 13:20:38 Updated: libssh2-devel-1.8.0-8.0.cf.rhel6.x86_64
```

this is my "locate" result of `libnghttp2.so.14` when i tried search:

```
[root@server ~]# locate libnghttp2.so.14
/opt/cpanel/nghttp2/lib/libnghttp2.so.14
/opt/cpanel/nghttp2/lib/libnghttp2.so.14.16.2
```

Comment: What version did you upgrade to/from? any ideas? I have no such file (`libnghttp2`) on any of my production boxes. It looks like that file is provided by `libnghttp2-1.6.0-1.el6.1.x86_64.rpm` ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/fedora/epel/6/x86_64/Packages/l/libnghttp2-1.6.0-1.el6.1.x86_64.rpm

Comment: Same Problem, any solutions?